# Reducibility of the polynomial $x^4+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that  $x^4+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 \,i)$ .Is true that  $x^{2n} +1 , n\ge3$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2\,i)$?

Is this correct to show that $x^4+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$? Is there another way to show that?
$$x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2=(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)$$

Is this correct to show that $x^4+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2\,i)$? Is there another way to show that?
$$x^4+1=(x^2-1)^2-(\sqrt2\,ix)^2=(x^2+\sqrt2\,ix-1)(x^2-\sqrt2\,ix-1)$$

How can I prove that  $x^{2n} +1 , n\ge3$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2\,i)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a polynomial is reducible if it is divisible by a non-constant polynomial of lesser degree... by factoring the polynomial, you have shown just that.

For the second question, notice that $x^{2n}+1$ factors into *integer* polynomial factors when $n$ is odd:

$$x^{2n}+1 = (x^2+1)(x^{2n-2}-x^{2n-4}+\ldots - x^2 + 1).$$

When $n$ is even, try slight modifications of your argument for $x^4+1$.

Comment: Hello, just one doubt factoring the polynomial $x^4+1$ in Q($\sqrt2$) is the same that factoring in Q($\sqrt2$)[x]?

Comment: $Q[\sqrt{2}][x]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $Q[\sqrt{2}]$. So when someone says factoring it in $Q[\sqrt{2}]$, that's really just shorthand for factoring in $Q[\sqrt{2}][x]$.